# Why is My ListView.builder() is NOT scrollable?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, scroll

I asked before for a way to get all the info from firebase with index "Which are Links To Videos", But now When these videos get out of the emulator borders, it throws `overflow with x pixels`, I tried to put it in `SingleChildScrollView`, didn't work and there is that property in ListView.builder(), `shrinkWrap`, Which should build a scrollable List, But obviously not, need some help.

> Code

```
return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('Khatma Collection')
            .document('Khatma 1')
            .collection('Videos')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  var link = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Link'];
                  var uploader = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Uploader'];
                  var likes = snapshot.data.documents[i].data['Likes'];
                  var like = likes.toString();
                  bool liked;
                  print({link, uploader, likes});
                  if (int.parse(like) > 0) {
                    liked = true;
                  } else if (int.parse(like) == 0) {
                    liked = false;
                  }
                  final videoPlayerController =
                      VideoPlayerController.network(link);
                  chewieController = ChewieController(
                    allowMuting: true,
                    autoInitialize: true,
                    deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: orientation,
                    allowFullScreen: true,
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
                  );
                  return SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Chewie(
                          controller: chewieController,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin:
                              EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 30),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                '$uploader',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  foreground: Paint()..shader = linearGradient,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 200),
                                child: LikeButton(
                                  likeCount: int.parse(like),
                                  isLiked: liked,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Comment: post the original code that throws "overflow with x pixels"`

Comment: @DeveloperOmar100 `Listview.builder` should be scrollable by itself. Why is it wrapped inside `SingleChildScrollView` ?

Comment: the widget tree like `SingleChildScrollView > ListView.builder > SingleChildScrollView` will never work as expected, why dont you start with the simple case like `ListView.builder`?

Comment: I did, but for some reason the listview can't be scrolled ?

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/basic-list and https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists

Comment: I know but I don't know why ?

Comment: It should scroll but I don't know but don't know why, that's why I used SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   body: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: 200, //maybe add a parent widget so it will have a height
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return Text("$index");
                  }),
            ),
          )),
```

Comment: I can't wrap it with a container don't know why but when I wrap it, the videos are not here anymore.

Comment: i think the video is still there but since your parent container might be so small with the aspectRatio of the video, the video dissapear.

Comment: Hmm I will see, Thanks

Comment: It throws this error `Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'`

Answer (score 2):

Add `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to `ListView.Builder`

```
 ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: Can you try to add SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), to your inner SingleChildScrollView

Comment: you want it to be scrolled or not to be scrolled?

Comment: to be scrolled.

Comment: try around the solutions which I gave you, it must be around that only

Comment: Can you comment out SingleChildScrollView and just have Container for that, Reason that is not working because ListView, SingleChildScrollView, Column all take the full screen be default. So you have to manage it, My Answer will be perfect for SingleChildScrollView+ ListView, but your SingleChildScrollView + Column causing this issue.

Comment: The container some how causes the disappearing of videos

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I was using the mediaQuery to identify the height while it needed a number like this
`Container( height: 200 )`,
not like `Container( height: height * n )`

Comment: I have now a problem which how to adapt to different phones.